# assign string components into variables

Tags: bash, shell-script, string, split

Looking for a smarter way to do something I'm doing already.

I have a string: "firstbit.secondbit.thirdbit.fourthbit.fifthbit.sixthbit"

The content between the periods changes, but the delimited position in the string is important.

This string will sometimes contain 3 parts only: "firstbit.secondbit.thirdbit"

I need to assign each part to a different variable. So, I'm currently using this uglyness:

```
#!/bin/sh
var="firstbit.secondbit.thirdbit.fourthbit.fifthbit.sixthbit"

first="$(echo $var | cut -d'.' -f1 )"
second="$(echo $var | cut -d'.' -f2 )"
third="$(echo $var | cut -d'.' -f3 )"
fourth="$(echo $var | cut -d'.' -f4 )"
fifth="$(echo $var | cut -d'.' -f5 )"
sixth="$(echo $var | cut -d'.' -f6 )"
```

What I'm hoping for is something more like:

```
echo "$var" | (magic command to assign values to variables here) first second third fourth fifth sixth
```

So that later on I can:

```
echo "[$first]"
```

[firstbit]

```
echo "[$third]"
```

[thirdbit]

and so on.

Arrays are no good as I prefer named variables for this system. Can't help but think that there's probably something in awk that can do this but I'm not intimately familiar with it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IFS=. read -r first second third fourth fifth <<< "$var"
```

This sets the field separator to "." then tells bash to read into the named variables from the input provided by your `$var`'s contents.

Comment: Beautiful - exactly what I was looking for. I'll admit: I had forgotten about <<<. Thanks Jeff. :)

Comment: Must the IFS assignment be on the same line? Does it need to be reset to its original value afterwards?

Comment: @RomainHautefeuille that syntax sets the IFS variable only for the command its own, it does not need to be reset afterwords. Try it! :)